# How to group by two fields in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab, crystal-reports-2010

Currently I can group just by one field not by two fields in a cross-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reports, you just select `Insert > Group` and add a second group.  For crosstabs, just add them to the Rows section.

If you want to have two physically separate statuses ("Temporary" and "Permanent") like in the picture, you'll want two physically separate crosstabs (the second of which will need to be in a subreport).

It would be easier to have one crosstab and just add the Status to the Row section.

Comment: That formatting is probably more complex than crosstabs can handle.  Like I said, you can add Employees and Team Leaders as groupings, but you need to clarify your question if you're having specific problems.

Comment: So, there is no way to group them in just one cross-tab ?  I have to create a sub-report ! right ?

Comment: Like I've said multiple times, you can add the Status as a Row grouping, but you won't have the separate crosstabs.  If you want separate crosstabs, create separate crosstabs, one for each status.

Comment: If I add the status to the row section, the results will be the same like the picture ??

Comment: I tried to do this before, I created two cross-tab and each one with status, but in my report I have customize select request, in this case i have to do two select request the first one with a where clause = "temporary" and the second one with a where clause = "Permanent", the problem is how to set two select request in just one report ? (I don't know if you see what i mean ? )

Comment: In your main report, have a crosstab for the Permanent workers.  Below that crosstab, create a subreport.  In that subreport, create a crosstab for the Temporary works, using the exact same query for the Permanent workers, except change the status so it only selects Temporary workers.

Comment: Thank you bro, you helped me a lot it finally work's, many thanks for you again .

Answer (score 2):

You should create a formula field that concatenates the text of these two fields, then use that formula as the field that you group on.